# ComboBox Dropdown Appears Beneath Window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, drop-down-menu

So I was have a combobox like below, coded like this;

```
AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Beige" BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="2">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label Name="lblText"></Label>
                    <ComboBox Name="cbxNumbers"></ComboBox>
                    <TextBox Name="txtNumbers" Visibility="Collapsed"></TextBox>
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="btnDone"
Click="btnDone_Click">That's Right!</Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1"
FontSize="8" Name="btnChangeInput" Click="btnChangeInput_Click">Let me chose the number
</Button>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

And then populated in code like this;

```
lblText.Content = Text;
cbxNumbers.Items.Add(5);
cbxNumbers.Items.Add(10);
cbxNumbers.Items.Add(50);
cbxNumbers.Items.Add(100);
cbxNumbers.Items.Add(1000);
cbxNumbers.Items.Add(10000);
cbxNumbers.Items.Add(100000);
cbxNumbers.Items.Add(1000000);
cbxNumbers.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

My question is obviously, why is my `Dropdown` showing beneath my window?

[image: ComboBoxProblem]

**UPDATE**

Quote Microsoft

> Thank you for reporting this issue. Though this issue is under
>   investigation, we will likely not have a fix available in .NET 4.0. We
>   will update this bug again when we are able to fix the issue in a
>   future release. Thanks!

Great... any ideas for a work around?

Comment: i'm also having the same issue in Telerik ASP.NET. 
Can somebody help me???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well documented bug with `AllowTransparency=TRUE`.  It only happens on some computers running Win XP.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/465964/wpf-combobox-dropdown-list-appears-behind-the-form-when-allowstransparency-true

A workaround is found [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/369500/problem-with-the-allowtransparency-and-popup-controls-in-wpf):

> As noted before, this is an issue with layered windows on XP. There is
>   not much that can be done at the WPF level to solve this, and given
>   that XP is no longer being serviced this isn't very likely to be
>   fixed. There are potentially workarounds you can employ, though.
>
> The source of the problem is that WPF uses something called "Layered
>   Windows" when WindowStyle=None and AllowsTransparency=True. Often the
>   reason for doing this is to implement custom window chrome. Recently
>   the WPF team published a library that allows you to get custom chrome
>   without resorting to layered windows. The library is available at
>
> http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell
>
> This doesn't support per-pixel opacity, but it does allow for
>   completely custom rendering of the window, including areas normally
>   managed by the system. It lets you set the radii of the windows
>   corners, but not have a completely arbitrary shape. If you can use
>   this library instead of AllowsTransparency=True then it should solve
>   this issue.

Microsoft has issued a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943326), but it seems to not have fixed all problems related to the issue.

Comment: Quote Microsoft "Thank you for reporting this issue. Though this issue is under investigation, we will likely not have a fix available in .NET 4.0. We will update this bug again when we are able to fix the issue in a future release. Thanks!". Great, any ideas for a work around?

Comment: @killianmcc just posted the workaround.  If you need custom chrome with popups you will need to use a different method of making custom chrome.

Comment: So it's just an XP issue? And the work around doesn't work with pop ups?

Comment: It is just an XP issue (and win server 2003 if you really care).  I'm not sure what you mean about the work around not working for popups.  You can turn off transparency on popups to fix the issue, but I don't think this works when you have custom chrome using `AllowTransparency=TRUE`.  The only other option is to use the alternative method of creating a custom chrome which I linked.